How do I create hook arrows in tikz diagram instead of plain arrows?
I need the tail of arrows in my diagram to be hooked how do I draw them? Here is the screenshot of current diagram with code.
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, every node/.style={scale=1}]
    % Nodes
    \node (L) at (0, 1) {$\mathcal{L}$};
    \node (R) at (0, -1) {$\mathcal{R}$};
    \node (H) at (-1, 0) {$\mathcal{H}$};
    \node (D) at (1, 0) {$\mathcal{D}$};
    \node (J) at (2, 0) {$\mathcal{J}$};
    
    % Arrows
    \draw[->] (H) -- (L);
    \draw[->] (H) -- (R);
    \draw[->] (L) -- (D);
    \draw[->] (R) -- (D);
    \draw[->] (D) -- (J);
\end{tikzpicture}



See herer: https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#section-arrows-meta . // Please post code, which compiles (yours doesn't at the moment). Thank you

It can also be an idea to use tikz-cd instead. It supports all sorts of arrows out of the box

Define a hookarrow style with the help of arrows.meta.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=2,
  %every node/.style={scale=1},% what for?
  hookarrow/.style={{Hooks[right]}->},
]
    % Nodes
    \node (L) at (0, 1) {$\mathcal{L}$};
    \node (R) at (0, -1) {$\mathcal{R}$};
    \node (H) at (-1, 0) {$\mathcal{H}$};
    \node (D) at (1, 0) {$\mathcal{D}$};
    \node (J) at (2, 0) {$\mathcal{J}$};

    % Arrows
    \draw[hookarrow] (H) -- (L);
    \draw[hookarrow] (H) -- (R);
    \draw[hookarrow] (L) -- (D);
    \draw[hookarrow] (R) -- (D);
    \draw[hookarrow] (D) -- (J);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Thank you. I tried this and it worked.
